# Vuex возвращает функцию вместо строки. Где ошибка?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

Подскажите пожалуйста, что я не так делаю. По задумке нужно отслеживать событие ввода в input, и введённый текст перезаписывать и хранить в store. В самом store записывать в localstorag, а потом при  запуске страницы по новой доставать значение из localstorage и передавать его из store в атрибут input'a value. И при каждом вводе собственно говоря перезаписывать. Но пока у меня в инпуте все время выводится вот это "function () { [native code] }". Что я делаю не так подскажите пожалуйста.

[![введите сюда описание изображения][1]][1]

HTML компонента login

```
  <f7-list form>
    <f7-list-input
      label="Username"
      name="username"
      placeholder="Username"
      type="text"
      :value="newUserName"
      @input="changeUsername"
      required validate
      pattern="[3-9a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁ]+"
    />
```

javascript

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      username: '',
      password: '',
    };
  },
  methods: {
    signIn() {
      const self = this;
      const app = self.$f7;
      const router = self.$f7router;
      router.back();
      app.dialog.alert(`Username: ${self.username}<br>Password: ${self.password}`, () => {
        router.back();
      });
    },
    changeUsername(){
        this.$store.commit(saveName);
    }
  },
};
```

store

import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';

Vue.use(Vuex);

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
    state:{
        userNameStor: 'newUserName',
        userPasswordStor:'',
    },
    mutations:{
        saveName(state, payload){
        state.userNameStor = payload;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Мутации ничего не должны возвращать.

Comment: убрал ,но эффект тот же

Comment: В store, у Вас нет переменной newUserName, которую Вы пытаетесь получить

Comment: Так вот же или нет ? state:{
        userNameStor: 'newUserName',

Comment: newUserName - в данном случае, значение, а userNameStor - "переменная"

Comment: Чуть код поправил. 3й день не могу разобраться уже крыша едет, туплю ужасно.  Как получить эту переменную, userNameStor  если её нет ? Я думал она по клику должна передаваться.

Comment: Измените :value="newUserName" на :value="username". Ещё у вас кавычки не стоят в названии мутации в файле js. И username не передаёте.